# How to disable 'no crontab for user' message in shell

Tags: shell, ssh, message, cron

I am doing this in my code

```
ssh -q username@ip 'crontab -l' > $PWD/crontab.txt
```

If the server has `crontab`, there's no problem it works. But if that server does NOT have crontab I get the message `no crontab for username`.

Is there a way to disable this message? When there is no crontab I don't want it to output anything.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Redirect stderr to /dev/null.

Comment: Like so `ssh -q username@ip 'crontab -l' > $PWD/crontab.txt >> /dev/null 2>&1` ??

Comment: `ssh -q username@ip 'crontab -l' > $PWD/crontab.txt 2> /dev/null`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older post, but I have been struggling with this too and have not been able to find a satisfying answer, until now. The reason I want to suppress this message is that I am writing a script that also adds a line to the crontab using the following lines, and have my own custom output for the user:

```
CRON_LINE='0 0 1 * * /path/to/my_script.sh'
(crontab -u antiftw -l; echo "$CRON_LINE" ) | crontab -u antiftw -
```

I have tried adding the usual redirects (as mentioned in the comments) at the end of the second line, but these both did not suppress the message:

```
2> /dev/null
>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

So, after some looking around and testing I found out that the reason that this message is shown is the fact that there is no file present at the location where the crontab is stored. In Ubuntu 20.04, this is:

```
/var/spool/cron/crontabs/
```

This file has the name of the user for whom we are creating a crontab:

> /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root for the root user

or

> /var/spool/cron/crontabs/antiftw for the user 'antiftw'

So in the case that we want to create a crontab for the user 'antiftw', we create an empty file at this location using:

```
touch /var/spool/cron/crontabs/antiftw
```

After this it is important to give this file the right owner/group and file permissions, or else we get the following error when trying to modify the crontab using the crontab command:

> crontab: crontabs/antiftw: rename: Operation not permitted

So we execute the following commands:

```
 chmod 600 /var/spool/cron/crontabs/antiftw
 chown antiftw:crontab /var/spool/cron/crontabs/antiftw
```

Note: If we want to do this for the root user, this changes to:

```
 chmod 600 /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
 chown root:crontab /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
```

Resulting in the following permissions:

> -rw------- 1 antiftw crontab

And now that we have prepared the file, we can just add our cron-lines without getting the message. To check whether the lines have been added correctly, we can use:

```
crontab -l
```

That will produce the recently added cronline.